# Fetch data with PHP and MySQL of a "text" column with special characters on it

Tags: php, mysql

I've a MySQL database that has this definition on one of its tables (theTable)

```
CREATE  TABLE `theDatabase`.`theTable` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `thecolumn` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

I'm trying this with PHP:

```
/*File executeSelect.php*/
mysql_connect("theServer","theUser","thePassword") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("theDatabase") or die (mysql_error());
$q = mysql_query($_REQUEST['query']);
while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[] = $e;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

If I do a `executeSelect.php?query=select * from theTable`, the information shown for the column `thecolumn` is `NULL` if `thecolumn` has special characters. I've `thecolumn` defined as `text` because I need to store large texts on it (500~1000 letters).

For example, a `executeSelect.php?query=select * from theTable` with `id=1;thecolumn=asdf` in `theTable` works OK, but the same executeSelect with `id=1;thecolumn=ásdf` in `theTable` gives `NULL` for `thecolumn`.

I've tried to execute the same query using the MySQL console and it works OK. I'm using Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.3.

What I'm misshing here that my php code doesn't retrieve data from `text` columns of MySQL in a right way?

Comment: What happens if you use this `$q = mysql_query("select * from theTable");`. You might be seeing a problem passing in your query from the querystring.

Comment: Oh - and mysql is deprecated - you should be using mysqli.

Comment: I've just read the mysqli thing, thanks for the tip. And no, `$q = mysql_query("select * from theTable");` doesn't give any errors. I've PHP with XDebug and development mode php.ini to show anything that goes bad.

Comment: Is the `id` data in the `json_ecode` output and just the `thecolumn` is null, or is both columns null? Have you also tried `echo $_REQUEST['query']` to see what the query looks like after pulling it from the url? Add `or die (mysql_error())` to the query - `$q = mysql_query($_REQUEST['query']) or die (mysql_error());`

Comment: Only `thecolumn` is `NULL` in `json_encode` result. `echo $_REQUEST['query']` shows everything ok (the exact same query that's sent is shown)

Comment: @Mike W tried the `mysqli` way, it gives the same error

Comment: I just set this up on my dev server (Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4, Mysql 5.5.31), and ran it. I got this back: `[{"id":"1","thecolumn":"Some text"},{"id":"2","thecolumn":"Some more text"},{"id":"3","thecolumn":"Third line of text"},{"id":"4","thecolumn":"Last line of text"}] `, so I guess what you're doing is OK, and the problem is elsewhere. Can you get any data at all back from a query?

Comment: @Mike W What happens if you put a very long string in `thecolumn`? It Works OK for me if the data in `thecolumn` is smaller tan 255 characters, but if I put something of 1000 chars in `thecolumn` I get the `NULL` thing...

Comment: @Mike W Already found what's trolling me... redid the question...

Comment: @mishamosher In that case you might have a character set problem. The character set should have been set at server level, or possibly at table definition time, but if it's wrong, or you have some sort of mismatch, you could have trouble. Take a look at [mysqli_set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php), which might give you a pointer

Comment: And yup, that's it!, it was just a matter of using a "utf8" charset to get everything working. If you want, you can repeat that in an answer to mark it as accepted answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 years, it bothers me that there is no answer in this question that solves my issue.

As pointed by **Mike W** in the comments of the question, the issue was with encoding in the sql client.

If using MySQLi, something like described in [**PHP: mysqli::set_charset - Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) can be used.

In my scenario, it was just a matter of doing a simple `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` right after opening the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise strongly against this as it's liable to SQL injection attacks from this kind of method

Comment: I'm aware of it, but it shows the idea of the problem that I'm experiencing in my main Project (which uses a secure way-of-work)

Comment: As Mike W suggests it could be the way the query is URLencoded

Comment: It's not. Already tried Mike W suggestion to use `$q = mysql_query("select * from theTable");` directly in the php file and don't use a POST way or a `?query=` in the URL. It always fail

Answer (score 0):

Should the code not be:

```
while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[] = $e['thecolumn'];
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

I would not recommend this method, and would recommend using PDO also